# Redirect BlackBerry device simulator output to console

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I'm currently developing a BlackBerry application using JDE 4.6.1 on Windows XP. Since I'm running the application directly from the console using fledge.exe I would like to know if there is a parameter for redirecting my application output, namely a simple system.out.println call, to the windows prompt console. Right now I'm able to view that output only on the Eclipse console window in Debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

The simulator only outputs through its [JDWP](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdwp-spec.html) interface.  If you don't want to use Eclipse, but are ok with a lighter-weight non-command-line tool, you can run the standalone debug server - you'll find a `jdwp.bat` file under your `eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpackX.X.X.X\bin directory`.

There may also be command line tools that let you print JDWP info, not sure as I haven't ever used one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to redirect the output, but you might consider using the BB event logger.  You can use a simple script to extract the logger output